# How to create separate certificates for users in freeradius ?

Tags: ssl-certificate, freeradius

All the computers in my network shares same certificate so i want to create separate certificate for users.
How to create separate certificates for users in freeradius ?

Answer (score 0):

```
edit client.cnf
make client.pem
then edit client.cnf again with the new user and
make client.pem again
```

and so on for all the users.